# vimgrep on file from STDIN?

Tags: vim

I like to open files and `grep` inside:

```
$ vim file
:vimgrep PATTERN %
:cwin
```

Now I get a nice buffer that I can click on `(set mouse=a)` to go between results.

However, this doesn't work with input from STDIN. E.g:

```
$ printf "hello\nworld\n" | vim - 
:vimgrep hello %
```

I get an empty file name error.

How do I `vimgrep` or equivalent for STDIN?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `vimgrep` requires a file argument based on the help:

```
:vim[grep][!] {pattern} {file} ...
        Search for {pattern} in the files {file} ... and set
        the error list to the matches.  Files matching
        'wildignore' are ignored; files in 'suffixes' are
        searched last.
```

When you try and use it as with your `printf ... | vim -` example the error even states as much:

> E499: Empty file name for '%' or '#', only works with ":p:h"

The `%` is a shorthand notation for whatever file you opened within `vim`. Given there's no file when piping via STDIN, you cannot do what you want.

When searching via `vim` there's basically 3 methods:

- :vimgrep
- :grep
- <kbd>/</kbd>

`vimgrep` is meant to do grepping of files from within `vim`. You use `:grep` to invoke the system's version of `grep` to search files either local or within the directory from where you've invoked `vim`. The <kbd>/</kbd> is meant for doing searches within the current buffer that you're actively in within `vim`.

This 3rd option would be the appropriate one to use for your scenario where you're searching within a buffer which was populated with content via STDIN.

#### temp file descriptor

As an alternative you can get the shell to create a temporary file descriptor by the creation of a temporary one, and sending the contents in via STDIN from this temporary file descriptor:

```
$ vim <(...)
```

You can see this like so:

```
$ ls -l <(echo hi)
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Aug  2 22:15 /dev/fd/63 -> pipe:[738943]
```

So you can trick `vim` into believing that the contents is coming from a file by using the above subshell `<(..)` instead of sending the data in via STDIN like so:

```
$ vim <(...cmds...)
```

#### References

- [When to use :grep and :vimgrep in vim?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9212/when-to-use-grep-and-vimgrep-in-vim)

Comment: Thank you, vim <(...)  did the trick. Good explanation and links.

Answer (score 1):

```
vim <(printf "hello\nworld\n")
```

Comment: How does this answer OP's question?

Comment: This works, although @slm's answer is a bit better at explaining things. +1 nevertheless.